# Regex Convert String-Contained Abbreviations to Title Case

Tags: php, regex, callback

As part of a simple URL cleaning/slugging function I'm extending, I need to make conversions such as the following:

```
Original               Converted
---------------------------------------------
USAMarch               UsaMarch
FETExaminations        FetExaminations      *
AnotherABBRString      AnotherAbbrString
LastONE                LastOne
```

(These are just examples, except for the second, which is what got me to doing this in the first place.)

I'm assuming I need to use `preg_replace_callback` to determine the position of any abbreviations and case them appropriately.

I haven't the foggiest of where to begin. Does anyone know what I can do to get this right?

### Update

Okay, I have this so far:

```
$input = preg_replace_callback("~([A-Z])([A-Z]+)([^a-z])([a-z]|)~",
function ($captures) {
   return $captures[1].strtolower($captures[2]).$captures[3].$captures[4];
},
$input);
```

Unfortunately, however, it doesn't work with strings where the abbreviation is last:

```
This                   Becomes
---------------------------------------------
LastONE                LastOnE
```

So I'm checking the *end* incorrectly, I assume. Also, this attempt isn't recursive. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you share what you may have tried?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't been able to figure out where to even begin... Everything I've thought out in my head wouldn't work. For example, I could match two capital letters in sequence, and then replace the second with its lower equivalent, but that will break new words...

Comment: For example, `AnotherABBRString` would become `AnotherAbbrstring`, which is not what I want it to do.

Comment: You would have to test each letter until you encountered a lowercase letter then back track.

Comment: Have updated my question. (Note: I'm not a Regex pro, so please bear with me...)

Comment: @MikeAnthony I'm just asking my self how should php know that these are 2 words? (`UsaMarch`) How does php know that? do you have dictionary array?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to have a dictionary, because there are just too many possibilities...

Comment: That said, you are quite right, @Rizier123. I can see how there is absolutely no perfect way to do this, due to the fact that there are so many possibilities. But hey, somebody may have a solution that is *almost* perfect, which, to me, is much better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These work with your examples.

Even finds stand alone caps.

```
 # Find:  '/([A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z]|\b)/'
 # Replace:  $1 . tolower($2)

 ( [A-Z] )                     # (1), Upper case
 ( [A-Z]+ )                    # (2), 1 or more upper case
 (?=                           # Lookahead assertion
      [A-Z]                         # Upper case
   |                              # or,
      \b                            # Word boundry
 )
```

Or, requires a lower case before possible end caps

```
 # Find:  '/([a-z])?([A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z]|(?(1)\b|(?!)))/'
 # Replace:  $1$2 . tolower($3)

 ( [a-z] )?                    # (1), optional lower case
 ( [A-Z] )                     # (2), Upper case
 ( [A-Z]+ )                    # (3), 1 or more upper case
 (?=                           # Lookahead assertion
      [A-Z]                         # Upper case
   |                              # or
      (?(1)                         # Conditional, does lower case precede this ?
           \b                            # yes, match boundry
        |  (?!)                          # or fail, this is a stand alone cap's
      )
 )
```

Comment: That is quite superb - thank you! This works for most cases, including those that I didn't list in my question.